# Identifying mark (Characters identified: 胡窯)

Tags: translation, character-identification, calligraphy

Can somebody please tell me what this mark means? I would be so very appreciative.

[image]

Comment: Looks like `胡烹`, [烹](https://shufa.supfree.net/raky.asp?zi=%C5%EB)

Answer (score 3):

The characters are 「胡窯」, a maker's mark for Japanese [arita ware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arita_ware). [Google search 胡窯](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E8%83%A1%E7%AA%AF) to get more information and image hits.

Comment: Naruhodo, japanese desu.